# How does yum determine what package is newer with multiple repositories enabled?

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I am trying to understand how yum is able to determine a particular package is newer when the system has multiple repositories enabled and a particular package may be available in one or all of the repos.

We are trying to create a custom package management system in order to manage our local repos and report to us if there are new updates available on all the servers vs what is available on the local repos.

Comment: That's what metadata is for. It keeps the package information and this information contains package versions. Yum parses the metadata and sorts the version.

Comment: rpmdevtools package has rpmdev-vercmp which can compare two version and tell you which one is bigger.

Answer (score 1):

yum looks for the "newest" version *and* release for a given package name.  It checks version first, and then release. If you give multiple repositories which have the same package name, yum will use the "newest" version (and release).

A comment by @msuchy mentions [rpmdev-vercmp](https://github.com/RsrchBoy/rpmdevtools/blob/master/rpmdev-vercmp) which you may find useful for analysis of RPM files.

Further reading:

- [Packaging:NamingGuidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines)
- [What's the meaning of the number which appears sometimes (when I use yum to install a fedora package) before a colon at the beginning of the name of the package?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/6987/whats-the-meaning-of-the-number-which-appears-sometimes-when-i-use-yum-to-install-a-fedora-package-before-a-colon-at-the-beginning-of-the-name-of-the/)
- [How to programmatically determine the highest version kernel RPM installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76597/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-highest-version-kernel-rpm-installed)
- [Comparing RPM versions in the shell](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/RPMShellVersionComparison)

Comment: How exactly does it judge based on the release? The package release often comes as a obscure string. I'm trying to figure out how yum is able to tell when comparing to what is install and what is "new", assuming the version number is the same, but package release was updated. Also, I think yum would try to keep to the same "family" of packages even though there is newer in another repo. Based on what I've seen. Say you have remi-php installed with additional dependencies, yum would prefer to keep the package in the same repo when asked to do a yum install/update.

Comment: I've seen yum jump to another repository when it sees a newer version (for the same package name), and don't see that it pays attention to "family".